# How to index a view that contains a union

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I want to create an index on a view but  my view uses a union. Please see example

```
SELECT     t_1.RiskID,
           t_1.HRASnapshotId,
           t_1.RiskDate, 
           t_1.RiskTypeDescription,
           t_1.AgillicUserId,
           t_1.SequenceNo, 
           t_1.RiskValue,
           t_1.RiskLevelDescription,
           t_1.OrganisationID
FROM       dbo.BE_Risks_Sequenced AS t
INNER JOIN dbo.BE_Risks_Sequenced AS t_1 ON 
           t.RiskTypeDescription = t_1.RiskTypeDescription 
           AND t.AgillicUserId = t_1.AgillicUserId 
           AND t.SequenceNo = t_1.SequenceNo + 1
WHERE     (t.RiskValue = 1) 
  AND     (t.RiskLevelDescription NOT LIKE t_1.RiskLevelDescription)

UNION ALL

SELECT     RiskID, HRASnapshotId, RiskDate, RiskTypeDescription, AgillicUserId, 
           SequenceNo, RiskValue, RiskLevelDescription, OrganisationID
FROM       dbo.BE_Risks_Sequenced
WHERE      (SequenceNo = 1) AND (RiskValue > 1)
ORDER BY   riskid asc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to fool the server.  The restrictions on indexed views are going to prevent a UNION no matter how you word it.  You also have a self join in your first query that's going to be another roadblock.

Two viable alternative options:

1)  Store a copy of your query output in a denormalized table and use triggers to synchronize it.  This is messy and resource inefficient, but it can perform well for reporting/analysis.

2)  Create some simpler intermediate views that can be indexed, and access them through a more complicated unindexed view that has the self join & union.  Use table hints like WITH(NOEXPAND) if necessary.

Comment: Are you able to give me an example how how i could change the view into simpler intermediate views that can be indexed?